# ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$ward_name'

Tags: php, laravel-4, orm, eloquent, belongs-to

I am trying to make relation between two models named as Wards and Beds. Table structure of ward is

```
    id | ward_naem| ward_type
    1  |  ENT     | male
    2  |  Heart   | male
```

Table of beds is

```
    id | ward_name| ward_id
    1  |  3       | 1
    2  |  3       | 1
    2  |  2       | 2
```

Relationship in Beds Model is

```
 public function wards()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('Wards');
  }
```

Relations is Wards model is

```
 public function beds()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('Beds');
}
```

In my controller i am writing these lines

```
public function index()
{
    $beds = Beds::all();

    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::make('adminipd.index',compact('beds'));
}
```

and when it redirect to index with object named `beds` I am retrieving `ward_name` with object of `$beds` as

```
 <td>{{{ $bed->wards()->ward_name}}}</td>
 <td>{{{ $bed->bed_no }}}</td>
```

It doesn't work and gives a blank page if I remove this line

```
 <td>{{{ $bed->wards()->ward_name}}}</td>
```

it works fine for "bed_no". In log file of my laravel project i got an error which is

> ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$ward_name'

Comment: What if you try `{{{ $bed->wards->ward_name }}}`?

Comment: i tried it but it also not working

Comment: In `ward` table column name you have a typo. `ward_naem` should be `ward_name`. Check if that typo exits in the database. If so it is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are using `wards()` with the parenthesis which will return you the relation not the data itself. Use `ward` instead without the parenthesis.

And also in your `wards` table you have a typo. `ward_naem` should be `ward_name`

Then change your `Bed` model to either this

```
public function ward() // changed from wards to ward
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Wards');
}
```

or this

```
public function wards() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Wards', 'ward_id'); // added the key
}
```

Then you can get all the beds with the ward like follows. This is not necessary, but good for performance.

```
$beds = Beds::with('ward')->get();
```

Then you can access bed name like follows.

```
{{ $bed->ward->ward_name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code from

```
  <td>{{{ $bed->wards()->ward_name}}}</td>
```

to

```
  <td>{{{ $bed->wards->ward_name}}}</td>
```

In fact you should rename **wards()** method to **ward()** for clearity as you are getting one instance not instances, because it is belongs to relation.